Error: 'A spread argument must either have a tuple type' in generic event listener wrapper
function existingFunc(arg1: number, arg2: string): number {
    return arg1 + arg2.length;
}

function wrapperFunc(...args: Parameters<typeof existingFunc>): ReturnType<typeof existingFunc> {
    return existingFunc(...args);
}

type EventMap = {
    DEBUG: (msg: string) => number;
    TICK: (num: number, num2: number) => string;
    NOTI: () => number;
};

function wrap<E extends keyof EventMap> (event: E, listener: EventMap[E]) {
    const wrapped = (...args: Parameters<typeof listener>) => {
        listener(...args);
    }

    return wrapped;
}

Playground
This code causes the error:
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. (2556)

at line 17:

The wrapperFunc above works fine, but why does wrap cause an error?

TS can't analyze generic conditional types very well, so Parameters<EventMap[E]> for generic E is essentially opaque to the compiler. If you want to make TS understand it you should use the technique described at ms/TS#47109 and shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes, it fully addresses the question. Thanks for answering!

uh but you accepted the other answer, not sure what to do here.

Add one more generic parameter for wrap function to change function listener's signature so that it takes rest parameter:
type EventMap = {
    DEBUG: (msg: string) => number;
    TICK: (num: number, num2: number) => string;
    NOTI: () => number;
};

function wrap<E extends keyof EventMap, F extends ((...args: [...Parameters<EventMap[E]>]) => ReturnType<EventMap[E]>)> (event: E, listener: F) {
    const wrapped = (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
        listener(...args);
    };

    return wrapped;
}

Playground
